# Problems with prime number

Tags: python, primes

I started learning python and today I wrote this code to find prime numbers:

```py
def is_prime(number):
    status = True
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            status = False
            break
        return status
```

It works but it doesn't identify number 2 as a prime number. Can anyone tell me what's my problem? Why does it return the value "None" for 2?

Comment: if the indentation here is correct, your `return status` is badly placed and will always only allow the loop to iterate once. Additionally, The reason your code returns a `None` for 2 is because you use a `break`. So the return statement is never encountered. Function ends without a return, that implicitly returns a None. Edit: and as sim correctly points out, it doesn't even enter the loop (because `range(2, 2)` )

Comment: to add to @Paritosh Sing: for `2` the loop is never even entered and `None` is returned because there is no return outside the loop.

Comment: `range(2,2)` return an empty list. So you don't go through in the for loop

Comment: As an aside, you should consider only go up to and including `number ** 0.5`

Comment: @Clément That's actually correct, because 2 is a prime number, and the return value should be True. As others have pointed out, here the issue is the placement of the return statement. There's another, different, issue with the list and it's that anything <= 2 will be considered prime, and that includes -4 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to do away with the break and format like so:

```
def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `range` should be `range(2, number+1)`. Otherwise, when entering `number=2`, the loop is not executed at all because `range(2, 2)` is empty:

```py
>>> list(range(2, 2))
[]
>>> list(range(2, 3))
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program returns empty at range function. please try the same

You should have added an else statement,

```
for i in range(2,num):
     if (num % i) == 0:
        return False

else:
           return True
```

Comment: The symbols `True` and `False` are capitalized in Python, the code doesn't run otherwise.  Also, semicolons aren't used in Python.  Finally, the `else` is optional in this context, simply moving the `return True` to where the `else` is works fine.